# ServiceStack session not being saved after authenticating from client

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I have implemented a custom authentication provider (CredentialsAuthProvider) to authenticate myself. Everything works perfect here. I authenticate via the following code in my ASP.NET Client application.

```
var res = Client.Post(new Authenticate
{
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = "admin",
    Password = "topsecret",
    RememberMe = true
});
```

TryAuthenticate in my custom CredentialsAuthProvider gets called, I return true if correct and `IHttpResult OnAuthenticated` gets called afterwards. Works perfect.

In my `OnAuthenticated` method I then set the value of some properties of my session. So I do something like this:

```
public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    try
    {
        // Save the browser cookie.
        if (authService.Request is IHttpResponse httpRes)
            httpRes.Cookies.AddPermanentCookie(HttpHeaders.XUserAuthId, session.UserAuthId);

        session.DisplayName = "MyName";
        session.IsAuthenticated = true;

        // Save the user session object (ServiceStack stores it in the in-memory cache).
        authService.SaveSession(session, TimeSpan.FromHours(5));

        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
    }
}
```

Also, until now everything works perfect.
Now, if I want to access a DTO that requires authentication (in my example `Products`), I still get `Unauthorized`. Even if I just authenticated and saved my session.

```
var response = Client.Get(new GetProducts());
```

I can see that my the method `IsAuthorized` in my custom AuthUserSession gets called, but looking at the properties of the base (AuthUserSession), **I can see that the properties I assigned earlier (DisplayName, IsAuthorized) still have their default value.**[image]

Question: Why are the properties I assigned in `OnAuthenticated` not being saved?

Thanks alot!

**EDIT:** I have realised that when I use this:

```
using (JsonServiceClient disposableClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:24131"))
{
    var res = disposableClient.Post(new Authenticate
    {
        provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
        UserName = "admin",
        Password = "topsecret",
        RememberMe = true
    });

    var response = disposableClient.Get(new GetProducts());
}
```

Instead of using my JsonServiceClient as a private class member, it works. But I dont want to authenticate everytime I try to access a ressource. Whats the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your Custom AuthProvider is unnecessary and already added by `OnAuthenticated()` which adds the `HttpHeaders.XUserAuthId` Cookie, sets `IsAuthenticated=true` and saves the Session which overrides your existing one, so basically your Custom Impl should be reduced to:

```
public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    session.DisplayName = "MyName";    
    return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
}
```

If you want to change how long the session is for you can override `OnSaveSession()` in your AppHost which will get called whenever the session is saved anywhere in ServiceStack:

```
public override void OnSaveSession(IRequest httpReq,IAuthSession session,TimeSpan? expiresIn=null) 
    => base.OnSaveSession(httpReq, session, TimeSpan.FromHours(5));
```

Also you don't have to `Dispose()` the `JsonServiceClient` which [has no effect](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/17f081b9906ac1568310c9b52cd31f0f034325c5/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServiceClientBase.cs#L1818). So your client code would just be:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:24131");
var response = client.Post(new Authenticate
{
    //Client libs usually don't have access to CredentialsAuthProvider
    provider = "credentials", 
    UserName = "admin",
    Password = "topsecret",
    RememberMe = true
});
```

Authenticating with the ServiceClient populates the [Session Cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) on that **client instance** which you would then be able to use to make authenticated requests:

```
var response = client.Get(new GetProducts());
```

Note the Session is [stored in the registered ICacheClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#can-be-used-with-any-icacheclient) so if your App Domain restarts it will lose all sessions. To preserve User Sessions across App restarts you can either use a [distributed caching provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching) (i.e. any Caching provider except for Memory) or use a [stateless Auth Provider like JWT](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) or [API Key Auth Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider).

If you're getting an UnAuthenticated Response and your App hasn't restarted (clearing all Sessions stored in the Memory Cache), have a look at the raw HTTP Headers using a packet/http sniffer like Fiddler or WireShark to check that the same [Session Cookies are being sent](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#cookie-session-ids) and that the Authenticated User Session [still exists in the cache](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#formatting-of-keys-used-in-cache-providers) at:

```
urn:iauthsession:{sessionId}
```

Where `{sessionId}` is the value of your `ss-pid` cookie.

Comment: "Authenticating with the ServiceClient populates the Session Cookies on that client instance which you would then be able to use to make authenticated requests:" That helped me alot. Thanks